# Xamarin Android Debugging Issue in VS 2017

Tags: android, debugging

We want to debug our android app with the real device but the project contains unmanaged projects (cpp pojects) and I think that this causes the problem.

We have the latest VS version (15.8.4) and when we try to debug, nothing happining after deploying. In the output window, we see

> Start debugging Android application ...
>        Starting Android application ...

A colleague could debug but after he updated the newest VS, he cannot debug as well and we do not know his VS version.

Is there anybody faced this problem?

OS: Windows 10
Android API: 24

Comment: is it in release mode?

Comment: @IntsabHaider, you mean in VS? If it is, we choose Debug. As I said, it was working with the previous version but after update it does not work. Somehow, new VS makes the problem

Comment: delete obj/bin folder, rebuild solution and look if it works now.

Comment: I did already but I think you did not understand the problem. Problem is regarding unmanaged projects in the solution. VS is newly installed to my computer and it has the same problem. So the solution should be related some settings or a patch install..

Comment: Have you tried looking into your build options (selecting the project root from solution explorer)? You should be able to look at various options for release and debug configurations. I don't know what cpp you are using (or if it even matters), but I can definitely tell you I've had numerous issues with the last 3-4 VS updates. Also, while you are there, do you have something called fast deploy on?

Comment: update to 15.8.5 and rebuild the app.